# Find list of words and replace with one word

Tags: sed, macos, epub

I have some `.epub` files of books I want to edit swear words out of for my younger kids to read. I've read `sed` is the right tool for the job (I am open to different solutions as well), but am new to it.

example original text

```
ant bat cat
dog eagle fish
```

modified text (post-sed)

```
ant XXX cat
XXX eagle XXX
```

I am on a Mac, and have got this to work:

`LC_ALL=C sed -E 's/bat|dog|fish/XXX/ig' temp1.txt > temp2.txt`

```
ant XXX cat
XXX eagle XXX
```

But I can't get this to work with the .epub file format
`LC_ALL=C sed -E 's/bat|dog|fish/XXX/ig' file1.epub > file2.epub`

Here's a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NfUsweqkzV1PGv00kMWPmmpZh3gwHXtG/view?usp=sharing) to an example `.epub` file.

Comment: epub are not text files...

Comment: Can you edit your post with a sample .epub file ?

Comment: sample file added.

Comment: What should be done about words like `verbatim`, `pseudogyne`, and `standoffish`, i.e. words that _contain_ the various strings that you specify?

Comment: @Kusalananda, good question. I guess I can come up with a comprehensive list that captures every variation of the profanities, or just replace any existence of them. With this project I'd probably start with the latter solution just to make sure I captured everything even if it errantly censors some things it shouldn't have and then maybe over time build up the comprehensive list to switch over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:
(you need [pandoc](/questions/tagged/pandoc) to be installed):

```
pandoc -f epub -t plain -o test1.txt test1.epub
sed -i'' -E 's/bat|dog|fish/XXX/ig' test1.txt
pandoc -f plain -t epub -o test1.epub test1.txt
```

Another incomplete approach:

```
unzip test1.epub
cd OPS
lynx -dump ./html/chapter*.html  | less
xmlstarlet edit # on the proper HTML files
cd -
zip -r test1.epub OPS
```